# statsmodels installation failed on ubuntu18.04 container host is redhat linux with firewall restrictions . but the error is Running cythonize failed

Tags: statsmodels

while installing the statsmodels getting failed on ubuntu18.04 container hosted on Redhat linux . Runtime Error: Running cythonize failed

```
#pip install statsmodels
```

in the docker container with ubuntu18.04 im trying to install statsmodels in python virtual environment . It is failed with " Running Cythonize failed". Numpy, pandas, scipy , patsy , cython==0.29 also installed.

Comment: work around this issue got fixed with the below commands:python3 -m pip install numpy~=1.24.0 scipy~=1.9.0 cython~=0.29.30 pandas~=1.5.0 patsy "setuptools_scm[toml]"
python3 -m pip install statsmodels --no-build-isolation

Answer (score 0):

Below commands resolved the issue with version incompatibility:

```
python3 -m pip install numpy~=1.24.0 scipy~=1.9.0 cython~=0.29.30 pandas~=1.5.0 patsy "setuptools_scm[toml]"
python3 -m pip install statsmodels --no-build-isolation
```